# DSL method not found: implementation()

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to add the Fresco library by to my project by adding this to my app-level gradle file

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'
```

Then I get the follwing error message:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()' Possible causes:
The project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade plugin to version 3.0.1 and sync project
The project may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin
```

When I run gradle --version it tells me that I am using gradle 4.5.

This is my top-level gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven"}
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app-level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project1.3"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "state1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    // lots of other dependencies
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'
}
```

I also have this in my gradle-wrapper.properties file.

```
distributionUrl= https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

I have basically tried everything from here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html but the problem persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide your app-level build.gradle too?

Comment: Done. Any ideas?

Comment: This only happens when you add  the 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8' dependency? Otherwise the project syncs well?

Comment: Yes, otherwise everything syncs perfectly.

Comment: Please add the other dependencies as well. There is a possibility that some other library may be in conflict with Facebook

Comment: @user5102612 did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that probably one of your other dependencies is causing the issue, 
I run the exact same app & project gradle files you provided in a new project and synced with no problem.

You can try the following:

1) substitute `implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'` with `compile'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'` (deprecated but it will help with the troubleshooting) and see if it will sync properly.

2) start a new project and use the same gradle file and see if the problem still exists.

If nothing works please post the complete app level gradle file to check again.